# spring boot not registering optional GET parameter

Tags: java, spring-boot, getparameter

I am following a tutorial and I have the following method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/viewstatus", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    ModelAndView viewStatus(ModelAndView modelAndView, int pageNumber) {

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("===========" + pageNumber + "===========");
        System.out.println();

        modelAndView.setViewName("app.viewStatus");

        return modelAndView;
    }
```

However when I go to `http://localhost:8080/viewstatus?p=11` I get the following error:

```
Optional int parameter 'pageNumber' is present but cannot be translated into a null value due to being declared as a primitive type. Consider declaring it as object wrapper for the corresponding primitive type.
```

I changed the `int` parameter to `Long` but then I get the following output in the console when I navigate to the same page:

```
===========null===========
```

The parameter is null, so it's basically not being recognized, but as far as I can tell I am following the tutorial to the letter, can you see a problem with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Add a `@RequestParam` annotation to map the url variable to the method argument

```
public ModelAndView viewStatus(ModelAndView modelAndView, 
                               @RequestParam("p") int pageNumber) {
```

Comment: That's not it. It seems to work if the get parameter in the url has the same name as the method parameter (pageNumber), but in the tutorial the guy has pageNumber as the method parameter and just "p" in the url.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@RequestParam` in the signature of your method, before the type and name of the parameter. The name must match with the url param. Remember that you have to use Wrapper classes because primitive types doesn't support null values.

Answer (score 0):

```
ModelAndView viewStatus(
    ModelAndView modelAndView, 
    @RequestParam(value = "p", required=false) Integer pageNumber
){
    //...
}
```

First use `@RequestParam` annotation to map the `GET` value to method argument. Then if you want to make that **parameter optional** you can specify the **`required`** attribute of `@RequestParam` to **false**.

If you want to assign some **`default value`** to params you can use `defaultValue` attribute.

> Note: If your GET params `KEY` name equals to `Method Argument` name then you don't have to use `value` attribute.

```
    ModelAndView viewStatus(
        ModelAndView modelAndView, 
        @RequestParam(required=false) Integer p
    ){
        //...
    }
```

---

Since you are using primitive `int` they can't hold the `null` value. So you can use `Wrapper` Class `Integer`. But do remember to use `@RequestParam` to map `GET` values to `method argument`